# factory boy cannot inherit from base factory with metaclass: `issubclass` error

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass, factory-boy

I'm fairly new to factory boy. I've got a model that gets created in different places in an object hierarchy, and with different attributes, depending on how it is used. In this case I have a picture that is either a logo or a profile pic.

This works fine:

```
class ProfileImageBase(factory.Factory):
    mimetype = 'png'
    image    = 'some bytes'

class UserProfileImage(ProfileImageBase):
    class Meta:
        model = models.media_models.ProfileImage
    parent = factory.SubFactory(BasicUser)
    id     = ProfileImage.PROFILE

class MerchantLogoImage(ProfileImageBase):
    class Meta:
        model = models.media_models.ProfileImage
    parent = factory.SubFactory(BasicMerchant)
    id     = ProfileImage.LOGO
```

Not very DRY eh? I'd like to put the Meta class in the base class, but this gives me crazy errors:

```
class ProfileImageBase(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.media_models.ProfileImage
    mimetype = 'png'
    image    = 'some bytes'

class UserProfileImage(ProfileImageBase):
    parent = factory.SubFactory(BasicUser)
    id     = ProfileImage.PROFILE

class MerchantLogoImage(ProfileImageBase):
    parent = factory.SubFactory(BasicMerchant)
    id     = ProfileImage.LOGO
```

Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/code/waxed_backend/src/waxed_backend/concerns/pictures/tests/view_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ....models.test_factories.profile_pictures import MerchantLogoImage
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/code/waxed_backend/src/waxed_backend/models/test_factories/profile_pictures.py", line 13, in <module>
    class UserProfileImage(ProfileImageBase):
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    params=attrs_params,
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 232, in contribute_to_class
    self.counter_reference = self._get_counter_reference()
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 259, in _get_counter_reference
    and issubclass(self.model, self.base_factory._meta.model)):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

My question is: wht on earth is happening here? I dont believe I'm doing anything novel.

Comment: I don't use factory-boy - but that being Python 2 - can you try inheriting this nested "Meta" class from "object" and see what happens?  (Classes not inheriting from object in Python 2 became a legacy base class that simply can break _a lot_ of stuff for being non conformant to new-style classes)

Comment: I've installed factory_boy her and could not replicate your issue.  - inheriting from a class and not redeclaring the `Meta` simply worked.

Comment: @jsbueno: I tried that... very strange. I'll play around some more. It seems to only be a problem with factory_boy if I dont inherit from Factory then it's not a problem